# Print commands in history consisting in just one word

Tags: regex, grep, history

I want to print lines that contains single word only.

For example:

```
this is a line
another line
one
more
line
last one
```

I want to get the ones with single word only

```
one
more
line
```

EDIT: Guys, thank you for answers. Almost all of the answers work for my test file. However I wanted to list single lines in bash history. When I try your answers like

```
history | your posted commands
```

all of them below fails. Some only prints some numbers (might line numbers?)

Comment: The `history` context changes the question! Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get all those commands in `history` that contain just one word. Considering that `history` prints the number of the command as a first column, you need to match those lines consisting in two words.

For this, you can say:

```
history | awk 'NF==2'
```

If you just want to print the command itself, say:

```
history | awk 'NF==2 {print $2}'
```

Comment: Yes, this one did the job. Thanks.

Comment: Good to read that. Remember you can accept the answer if you are done. Also, I clarified the title in your question to avoid confusions.

Answer (score 2):

To rehash your problem, any  line containing a  space or nothing should be removed.

```
grep -Ev '^$| ' file
```

Your problem  statement is unspecific on whether lines containing only punctuation might also occur. Maybe try

```
grep -Ex '[A-Za-z]+' file
```

to only match lines containing only one or more alphabetics. (The `-x` option implicitly anchors the pattern -- it requires the entire line to match.)

In Bash, the output from `history` is decorated with line numbers; maybe try

```
history | grep -E '^ *[0-9]+  [A-Za-z]+$'
```

to match lines where the line number is followed by a single alphanumeric token. Notice that there will be two spaces between the line number and the command.

In all cases above, the `-E` selects extended regular expression matching, aka `egrep` (basic RE aka traditional `grep`  does not support e.g. the `+` operator, though it's available as `\+`).

Comment: When I run it like `grep -ex "[A-Za-z]+" test.txt`   I get    `grep: [A-Za-z]+: No such file or directory`

Comment: Sorry, my bad; `-E` not lowercase `-e`. Answer updated.

Comment: may be good to say `grep -E '^ *[0-9]+ +[A-Za-z]+$'`, that is, multiple spaces can occur after the digits (in my case, 2).

Comment: @tripleee
Thank you for explanation. I tried your last command `history | grep -E '^ *[0-9]+ [A-Za-z]+$' ` but it returns nothing.

Comment: @tripleee
I suspect that `.bash_history` has different format.

Comment: @fedorqui Out of the box, commands with a  space in front are omitted from the history. To be completely robust, you might still want to accept leading spaces, but only a small minority of users will ever have them.

Comment: However, there will be two spaces between the line number and the command. Updated answer again.

Comment: No, this is not what I mean. What I wanted to say is that `history` displays the commands in the format `N` + `space` + `space` + `command`, at least in my computer. So I suggested you to change the regex to allow multiple spaces after the digit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grep -E '^\s*\S+\s*$' file
```

With the above input, it will output:

```
one
more
line
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file as texts.txt and if `grep` is not the only criteria; then

```
awk '{ if ( NF == 1 ) print }' texts.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If your test strings are in a file called in.txt, you can try the following:

```
grep -E "^\w+$" in.txt
```

What it means is:

```
^ starting the line with
\w any word character [a-zA-Z0-9]
+ there should be at least 1 of those characters or more
$ line end
```

And output would be

```
one
more
line
```

Answer (score 1):

If your single worded lines don't have a space at the end you can also search for lines without an empty space :

```
grep -v " "
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you're looking for could be best described as a `newline` followed by a `word` with a negative lookahead for a `space`,

```
 /\n\w+\b(?! )/g
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/hK8pG5/1)